# Removing text editor annotation types

Tags: eclipse, annotations, editor, eclipse-rcp, markers

I want to remove annotation type from annotation types inside eclipse based RCP. The list can be found inside Window->preferences->general->editors-Text Editors->Annotations, and amont annotation types i have:

Breakpoints (org.eclipse.cdt.debug.core.breakpoint)
Breakpoints (org.eclipse.debug.core.breakpoint)

I want to remove the 1st one for example. Is there a way to do it programmatically or by changing plugin.xml?

Answer (score 5):

To turn off annotations, you have to select **Revisions > Hide Revision Information** from the annotation bar context menu in eclipse. see the this link for more details. http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-cvs-annotate.htm

Comment: The question asks for a way to remove an eclipse built-in annotation and your provided answer and link is how to track code annotations. These are not the same.